# How to perform line by line operation(some x) on a CSV file using c++

Tags: c++, sqlite, csv, c++11, getline

I have been struggling with the whole line(\n or \r) thing, i was assigned myself a task to read a .csv file that contains 4K lines in it..with my curiosity i have found the way to read the csv file and separate each field/word from the delimiter ','.

```
std::istream& safeGetline(std::istream& is, std::string& t)
{
    t.clear();
    std::istream::sentry se(is);
    std::streambuf* sb = is.rdbuf();

    for(;;) {
        int c = sb->sbumpc();
        switch (c) {
        case '\r':
            if(sb->sgetc() == '\n')
                sb->sbumpc();
            return is;
        case EOF:
            // Also handle the case when the last line has no line ending
            if(t.empty())
                is.setstate(std::ios::eofbit);
            return is;
        default:
            t += (char)c;
        }
    }
}

    int main()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the file path :";
        string filename;
        cin>>filename;
        ifstream file;
        file.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in);
        vector<string>arr;
        string content;
        string arr2;
        stringstream ss;
       // sqlite3 *db;int rc;sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
        int i=0;
         while (!safeGetline(file,content).eof())--here is the problem
        {
            ss<<content;
    //since some of the field content falls next line i have decided to remove the '\n'
            content.erase(std::remove(content.begin(), content.end(), '\n'), content.end());
            while (getline(ss,arr2,','))
            {
               arr.push_back(arr2);
            }
       }
}
```

here  this `while (!safeGetline(file,content).eof())`--i thought this code will read the first line from the CSV file and gone through `while (getline(ss,arr2,','))` for delimiter seperation,but what happenning is that the `safeGetline()` as well as the normal `getline()`--which i tried before instead of `safeGetline()` read the entire content and come through the delimiter seperation part this makes me hard to insert those fields in the DB

ex:

```
4xxxxxx,"field2",field3,,,,field7
400x1x2,"field2",,field4,,,field7
```

After the code start read, The while (!safeGetline(file,content).eof()) returns

output:

4`xxxxxx,"field2",field3,,,,field7400x1x2,"field2",,field4,,,field7`

Here the field7 and the value 400x1x2 which was present at the second line got combined `field7400x1x2`--this gives bogus result when i insert those fields into my table(i.e) values are cluttered improperly inside the table.

So how could i really perform line by line read operation(i.e) in my case read->seperate delimeter->push to vector->insert to table->second read->.....

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement

```
    switch (c) {
    case '\r':
        if(sb->sgetc() == '\n')
            sb->sbumpc();
        return is;
    case EOF:
        // Also handle the case when the last line has no line ending
        if(t.empty())
            is.setstate(std::ios::eofbit);
        return is;
    default:
        t += (char)c;
    }
```

detects just the '\r' or '\r\n' case. It is unable to handle files with '\n' character alone.

So change it like this:

```
    case '\n':
    case '\r':
        if(sb->sgetc() == '\n' || sb->sgetc() == '\r')
            sb->sbumpc();
        return is;
```

Comment: i intentionally removed that case:'\n' from the function, since my end line denote CRLF and some of the columns or fields in the CSV contain LF inside it ,i took the stance to remove that, nothing problem with reading---except the getline() or safegetline() read the entire data at once..i have been losting  the sequence which i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to keep the CRLF sequences in the original input. From the looks of it you are working on a Windows system where `std::ifstream` opened in text mode will be opened in a way conflating CRLF-sequences into individual `'\n'` characters. The difference between text and binary mode is exactly the translation of line end sequences or the absence thereof. Open your file using

```
file.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
```

Note that the conventional approach is to *not* use `eof()` to indicate read failure. Instead, `std::ios_base::eofbit` is to be set when stream touched end of file. Failure to read a format is indicated using `std::ios_base::failbit` and the canonical approach to loop of the reads would be:

```
while (safeGetline(file, content)) {
   // ...
}
```

Streams convert to `true` when neither `std::ios_base::failbit` nor `std::ios_base::badbit` are set.